# \chardef and underscore

Tags: fonts, symbols

Could you explain to me why

```
a\_b {\ttfamily a\_b} \\
\chardef\_=`\_
a\_b {\ttfamily a\_b}
```

produces

[image]

?

I would like to have the short underscore in the normal text and the long one in fixed-width font. I cannot change `{\ttfamily a\_b}`. The other `a\_b` I can change.

Thanks for your help!

---

EDIT: I realized that `a\textunderscore b` solves my immediate problem in text. I would still like to know where the mysterious dot is comming from.

In math mode,

```
\chardef\_=`\_
$a\_b$
```

LaTeX stops compiling altogether on my installation (without error, it just halts).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `\chardef` defines `\_` to be the character in position "5F (ASCII for the underscore character), and that position just happens to contain the mysterious dot. At least it does in cmr10, and apparently it does in the font you're using as well (run `(pdf)tex testfont` to make font tables for any font you're curious about). The standard definition of `\_` in plain TeX just typesets a rule of some suitable width, as there isn't any underscore glyph in the cmr font. I assume something similar is true in LaTeX, though I haven't bother to dig my way past the `\textunderscore` magic.

I am not too sure about what you can do, though. The whole LaTeX font selection business is a weak point of my TeX foo.

Answer (score 6):

In a fix-width font every symbol should have the same width. So a long underscore is a bit unusual. In any case: in OT1-encoding (which you are obviously using) `\_` calls internally `\textunderscore`, which in turn is define as a rule of width 0.3em and some space. You can redefine `\_` to get a longer rule and use `\textunderscore` at other places:

```
\documentclass{book}
\DeclareTextCommand{\_}{OT1}{%
  \leavevmode \kern.06em\vbox{\hrule width.6em}}

\begin{document}
a\textunderscore b  {\ttfamily a\_b}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]