# Have just the file name show up in a listing environment

Tags: listings, tcbinputlisting

How to get just the file name (sometimes with an underscore "_") to show up in the code environment if the actual listing file is in another location like `../Matlabcode/sol2_adx.m` instead of something like this with the full path:

[image]

In this example, the title of the code should be `sol2_adx.m`

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}}$}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{matlab}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{codeblock}[2][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm},
        after upper={\centering\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},#1}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter]{\inputmatlab}[3][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#3},%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize},
     after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
     frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
     %
     listing file={#3},#1}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{filecontents*}{sol2_adx.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\inputmatlab{Expansion Algorithm}{sol2_adx.m}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the listing: [picture, click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFcNc.png)

Comment: @egreg, yes, that is correct. The example code given will produce that output.  As I stated in the problem, if the matlab file is under a different folder, the folder path then the name is output.  To see the problem that I am having, probably created the .m file under a different folder and then you will see the output like that shown in the figure.  Thanks!

Comment: Edited file to generate a .m file with an "_".  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little help from [Extracting the basename from a filepath argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65345/extracting-the-basename-from-a-filepath-argument) and [How to display filenames with underscores.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4408/how-to-display-filenames-with-underscores) here is a simplified MWE showing how to do what you want.

In this example `sol2_adx.m` is placed in a subdirectory called `subdir`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

% use \filename@parse to strip the path from filename
% also allow underscore in filename
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`_\active
\gdef\strippath#1{%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`_\active
  \let_\textunderscore
  \edef\fname{\filename@base .\filename@ext}%
  \scantokens\expandafter{\fname}%
  \endgroup
}
\endgroup
\makeatother

% simplified inputlisting definition
% note before upper uses \strippath defined above
\newtcbinputlisting{\inputmatlab}[3][]{%
  before upper = \textbf{\strippath{#3}},
  listing only,
  listing options = {#1,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\ttfamily},
  listing file = {#3},
  #1}

\begin{document}
\inputmatlab{Expansion Algorithm}{subdir/sol2_adx.m}    
\end{document}
```

[image]